"scope" field in bearer token with OAuth2-proxy
I configured oauth2-proxy for authentication for one of my applications. My application checks the scopes to determine access to resources.
I am successfully able to send the bearer token requested by oauth2-proxy, but the "scope" field is not present within the JWT;
I can only include the "groups" field. How can I insert it? In fact, compared to when I generate the token with a curl, many fields are missing.
Thank you in advance.
Oauth2 configuration:
OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET=secret
OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID="app.pippo.it"
OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET=secret
OAUTH2_PROXY_EMAIL_DOMAINS=*
OAUTH2_PROXY_SKIP_JWT_BEARER_TOKENS=false
OAUTH2_PROXY_REDIRECT_URL="http://app.pippo.it:9999/oauth2/callback"
OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAMS="http://app_proxy"
OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:4180
OAUTH2_PROXY_SESSION_STORE_TYPE=redis
OAUTH2_PROXY_REDIS_CONNECTION_URL=redis://redis:6379
OAUTH2_PROXY_REVERSE_PROXY=true
OAUTH2_PROXY_SCOPE=openid email profile offline_access
OAUTH2_PROXY_SKIP_PROVIDER_BUTTON=true
OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_USER_HEADERS=true
OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_XAUTHREQUEST=true
OAUTH2_PROXY_OIDC_ISSUER_URL=https://keycloak.pippo.it/realms/LinkersysSviluppo
OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER=keycloak-oidc
OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER_DISPLAY_NAME=Keycloak
OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECURE=false
OAUTH2_PROXY_WHITELIST_DOMAINS=*.pippo.it
OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_DOMAINS=pippo.it
OAUTH2_PROXY_INSECURE_OIDC_ALLOW_UNVERIFIED_EMAIL=false
OAUTH2_PROXY_SET_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER=true
OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER=true
OAUTH2_PROXY_PASS_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN=true
OAUTH2_PROXY_SKIP_AUTH_STRIP_HEADERS=false
OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAM_TIMEOUT=300s

